# CommonJS require won't work inside Jest test file

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am testing my backend with Jest, but I keep getting this error

```
\node_modules\generate-key\lib\generate.coffee:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){rn = (max) ->
                                                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1796:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/generate-key/index.js:2:18)
```

This is my jest config file:

```
   module.exports = { clearMocks: true, coverageDirectory: 'coverage', testEnvironment: 'node',moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'json', 'node'] };
```

My test file:

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
const { getConvertedKind } = require('../common');

test('check', () => {
  expect(3).toBe(3);
});
```

The imported function:

```
exports.getConvertedKind = kind => {
  const kinds = {
    cinemaPass: 'cinema',
    hotelPass: 'hotel',
    boardingPass: 'flight',
    coupon: 'coupon',
    eventTicket: 'event',
    transit: 'transit',
    storeCard: 'wallet',
    offer: 'offer'
  };
  return kinds[String(kind)] || null;
};
```

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "nodemon server.js",
"start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js",
"debug": "ndb server.js",
"test": "jest --config ./jest.config.js"
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to load a `.coffee` file and by default jest doesn't transform node_modules.

You can check the [transformIgnorePatterns](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring) option and try something like:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/(?!generate-key)"],
```

Comment: I tried this but the issue persists. I updated the question with the scripts section in package.json file